# integrating $\int_{x_0}^{x}\arccos(a-\cos(x'))dx'$

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I've been looking at an integral of the form 
$$\int_{x_0}^{x}\arccos(a-\cos(x'))dx'.$$ We can set $x_0$ as to give no contribution from the lower limit. I've tried to set $\arccos(x)=\pi/2-\arcsin(x)$, to simplify it.

I achieve the form
$$\int\frac{v\cos(v)}{\sqrt{1-(a-\sin(v))^2}}dv,$$ by setting $\sin(v)=a-\cos(x)$, I have also ignored the limits to focus on the integrand. I have looked at the table of integrals and series to see if there was a solution for this integral, but no luck. Does anybody possibly know a technique for solving it?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but it is possible that some better answer comes along

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I can see what you did, I'm just trying to work through it to see if I can find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be more careful and explicitly write the limits every time.

$$I(a,b,c)=\int_b^c \arccos(a-\cos(y))dy$$

$$y=\arccos z$$

$$dy = -\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

$$I=\int_{\cos b}^{\cos c} \arccos(a-z)\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

$$z=a-u$$

$$u=a-z$$

$$I=\int_{a-\cos c}^{a-\cos b} \arccos(u)\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(a-u)^2}}$$

$$u=\cos v$$

$$v=\arccos u$$

$$du=- \sin v$$

$$I=\int_{\arccos(a-\cos b)}^{\arccos(a-\cos c)} \frac{v \sin v dv}{\sqrt{1-(a-\cos v)^2}}$$

Yes, this is not fun.

---

Let's get a little back:

$$I=\int_{a-\cos c}^{a-\cos b} \arccos(u)\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(a-u)^2}}$$

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{a-\cos c}^{a-\cos b} \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(a-u)^2}}-\int_0^1 \int_{a-\cos c}^{a-\cos b} \frac{u du dt}{\sqrt{1-u^2 t^2}\sqrt{1-(a-u)^2}}$$

First integral is elementary, second integral w.r.t. u is most likely incomplete elliptic integral. Some transformations are required, but this is what I would suggest. Integrating w.r.t. $u$ first, using special functions, then taking the $t$ integral.

Comment: How did you get the second step after "Let's get a little back"

Comment: @Arbuja, $$\arccos u = \frac{\pi}{2} -\arcsin u$$ and the integral for $\arcsin$ is well known

Comment: and then he used an integral representation of $\arcsin$ to get the two integrals